# JFileChooser Remembering Previously Selected File

Tags: java, swing, awt, jfilechooser

Right now, I have my own custom file chooser class. This is only for viewing image files. This custom class allows you to preview the image and everything (using "setAccessory(Component c)"). My question is: when someone selects a photo and opens it, then that person decides to switch the photo, how can I make my custom file chooser, when opened again, start at the file that he or she previously selected (in terms of like alphabetical order).

For instance, I pick a file called "john.png". I decide I want to switch to "zomb.png". When I reopen JFileChooser, instead of starting at "amy.png" (the very first file), it will start at "john.png".

With my custom file chooser, I have already implemented this feature for my image preview. Where I am having problems is the FilePane. I've tried "setSelectedFile(File f)", but all that does is change the "File Name:" textfield to be that file.

Comment: I've had a quick look through it and it doesn't seem to be possible.  In fact, the moment that the file name field gains focus (at least under the windows look and feel), the UI delgate clears the `FilePanel`'s selection :P

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually figured it out with your answer (you deleted it tho so I can't upvote..) I wasn't making only one instance of my file chooser. I kept making a new one every time I pressed a button that brought it up. Thanks.